# android osmand api with am commands

Tags: android, adb, termux, osmand

on my android phone I want to control osmand using the [osmand api](https://github.com/osmandapp/osmand-api-demo/tree/master/OsmAnd-api-sample). To send the intents  I want to use the `am` command available in adb shell or termux.

I am able to start osmand with `am start net.osmand.plus/net.osmand.plus.activities.MapActivity`

In my first test I just want to stop the navigation (command: `STOP_NAVIGATION`).

First I tried `am start -a stop_navigation -n net.osmand.plus/net.osmand.plus.activities.MapActivity`. The result was `Starting: Intent { act=stop_navigation cmp=net.osmand.plus/.activities.MapActivity } Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front`, which makes sense.

Then I tested some broadcast commands, e.g.:

- `am broadcast -a stop_navigation -n net.osmand.plus/net.osmand.plus.activities.MapActivity`
- `am broadcast osmand.api://stop_navigation`

I also tested it with capital letters. But no command was successful.

Is there someone which has more experiences with android intents and / or osmand api and can help me how to create a working command?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution, it was simpler than expected. Maybe I can help someone with the solution:

The command `am start osmand.api://pause_navigation` is enough.

BTW:
`termux-open osmand.api://pause_navigation` does also work.